# Facebook Like NewsFeed

Tags: database, facebook, database-design, twitter

i would like to design facebook like newsfeed module,but I dont know right and efficient method to do it.I want to design its database in a way with speed updates retrieval time and with 90% of accuracy I am using follow like concept.how to do it?.please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an App similar to the News Feed. You can download the source code to study the functionality for the News Feed.
[Click here](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/05/facebook-wall-script-with-php-and.html) to go to the App